# Disable Webpart Somewhere Other than Webparts Maint. Page

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am getting a "Server Out of Memory Error" on my sharepoint site and I think it is linked to a corrupt webpart.  Problem is I cannot navigate to the Webparts Maintenance Page to disable webparts for troubleshooting.  Is there any other place I can disable all my Webparts then enable them one by one to find the corrupt one? I tried in Sharepoint 2010 Designer but it doesn't seem possible from there.

Comment: Dis you checked anything on ULS logs?

Comment: Here is this entry...
Process: w3wp.exe
Message: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Comment: It's an out of memory error, but I have tripled the memory associated with that virtual machine and the error didn't change

Comment: append your url with contents=1 at the end and check if the web part maintenance page is opening.

Comment: if you read the original post I state that I cannot navigate to the webparts maintenance page, I get the same error.

Comment: I have read your post you should have your site page url right.. append that url with contents=1 and try if you were able to peak into the maintenance page.

Comment: and like I said, the same error I get when navigating to www.mysite.com I get when I navigate to www.mysite.com?contents=1

Comment: Can you recycle your app pools and do IIS reset and restart your windows .Give it a try some times some processes eats away the RAM .

Comment: I tried that several times, along with restarting the actual server.  It looks like we will be restoring out site from a backup.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure what the problem was, but a restore fixed it